# Does google prediction api work for image recogniton

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, object-recognition, google-prediction

I read the official documentation for the api, but I wanted to make sure that it's possible for it to perform object recognition in images. More specifically, my idea is to provide a lot of images of parking lots with the number of parking spots currently available. I wanna get a model to predict how many spots are available given an image of the parking lot.

Does anybody have previous experience with using the API for a similar goal?

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think google prediction api will works for image recognition.

because prediction api knows only numeric and string.

for image recognition Google Vision Api is the best , i think it cant able to recognize humans or persons but it is recognize place like eiffel tower and all.

even it can able to read the image written strings.